# How to ask "when do you open" and "when do you close"?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

In a shop or any other public place I can ask "¿Cuál es tu horario?" to mean what are the working hours, right?

But I want to ask precisely when they open and when close.

What'll be the proper way to ask this?

And what form of a verb will I use?

> "Tu/Usted?"

Or

> "They"?
>
> "Se + verb"?

Comment: I usually use "ustedes": ¿Cuándo abren? and ¿Cuándo cierran?

Comment: @FGSUZ what's the most common way: ustedes or as `TaD` suggested "this place"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you can use:

> "¿A qué hora abre?"

to ask for when they open.

And to ask for when they close,

> "¿A qué hora cierra".

I'm from Argentina and we use this form to ask these questions!

Comment: does `abre/cierra` refer to "you" as a person/staff member or "this place"?

Comment: refers to `"this place"`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively why not ask

> ¿Cuándo se abre? or ¿Cuándo se cierra?

where the subject is now the thing which is either opening or closing. You could substitute "A qué hora" for "Cuándo" of course.